# Internal differences between latching solenoid and Stepper Motor

Tags: electrical-engineering

It is my understanding that basic latching solenoid consist of coil, magnet, spring, two electrical wire, electrical connector, enclosure and armature plunger. My assumptions are based on [Latching Solenoid Theory](http://www.tlxtech.com/understanding-solenoids/theory-operation/latching-solenoid-theory)

[image]

A basic 4 wire stepper motor consist of 2 additional coils, magnet, four electrical wire, enclosure and electrical connector. My assumptions are based on [Intro to Stepper Motors](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5789/2012/Slides/Steppersx2.pdf).

[image]

The above are my basic understanding with regard to internal differences and similarities between the two components. I understand vendors will include addition feature to differentiate themselves from competition.

**Questions:** Are there any other standard subcompacts that are missing in this basic analysis?

Comment: I am plan to use this information to do a material and cost analysis.

Comment: They don't do the same thing. Stepping motors rotate continuously and latching solenoids move between two positions (generally linear motion). If you are trying to use them to accomplish the same thing there will be additional components that also factor into cost, for instance drive electronics.

Comment: @EricShain, I understand they don't to the same thing. A solenoid to a most part will offer a binary output and a stepping motor will offer kind of continuous output as you stated in your comment. No I am not trying to accomplish output from both the components.